# jQuery tonum is grater then fromno if wrong show error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action='insert.php' method='post' id='myform' >
  <p>
    <input type='text' name='fromno' placeholder='fromno' id='fromno' /><input type='text' name='tonum' placeholder='tonum' id='tonum' />
  </p>
  <button id='insert'>Insert</button>
  <p id='result'></p>
  <script src='insert.js'></script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to check with jQuery if `tonum` is grater then `fromno`

If `tonum` is below `fromno` then it should show an error.

Comment: You should take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
 You should also show what you tried (we don't do your [home]work)

Comment: `parseInt($("#tonum").val()) > parseInt($("#fromno").val())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check inline comments for detailed explanation

```js
$('#insert').on('click', function() {
  var fromnum = $("#fromno").val();//get fromnum value
  var tonum = $("#tonum").val();//get tonum value
  if (fromnum != "" && tonum != "") {//check if both are not empty
    if (parseInt(tonum) > parseInt(fromnum)) {//check if tonum is greater than fromnum
      $("#result").text('Correct').addClass('valid');
      //display result or continue with other code
    } else {
      $("#result").text('To num should be greater than From num').removeClass('valid');
      //display error
    }
  } else
    $("#result").text('Both fields has to be filled').removeClass('valid');
    //display error if either of the field is empty
});
```

```css
/*Just for UI purpose*/
#result {
  color: red;
}
.valid {
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='insert.php' method='post' id='myform'>
  <p>
    <input type='text' name='fromno' placeholder='fromno' id='fromno' />
    <input type='text' name='tonum' placeholder='tonum' id='tonum' />
  </p>
  <button id='insert'>Insert</button>
  <p id='result'></p>
  <script src='insert.js'></script>
</form>
```

Comment: better to close the question

Comment: @Jai.. Voted for that.. Shall I delete the answer too?

Comment: By the time I posted the answer, all these comments and downvotes came in.. Never had an eye on that... :(

Comment: not really just put it as is, good for OP to have some answer for the question though.

Comment: Alright @Jai.. thank you.. :)

Comment: Thanks for Works good please update only number input also paste text replace

Comment: some time simple Q forget Ans

Comment: sir i tried when clicked show error and open insert.php

Comment: but if show error not post insert.php

Comment: @A.Sang.. This question is already closed and this answer just solves the issue you had in question. I request you to create a new question for your current issue with some detailed information on it.. Happy Coding.. :)